# Android socket timeout issue when phone locked

Tags: android, sockets

We have a server listening to tcp packets using sockets.

I am trying to develop an android client to communicate with the server.

The problem is when the app
-goes in background
or
-there is no activity
or
-phone locked.
the channel goes down **"Timeout Error"** From the server.

I tried to send an empty tcp packet every 1min

```
// heartbeat every 1 min
ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
               client.send(HeartBeatMsg.Instance);
            }
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

but still not working.

How to keep alive the communication channel ?

```
//region TCP connection
                    Socket mSocket = new Socket(mServer, mPort);
                    InputStream inputStream = mSocket.getInputStream();
                    mOutStream = mSocket.getOutputStream();
```

Comment: You can't. That's how Android works. Unused resources are aggressively freed to save battery.

Comment: more details please

Comment: What do you mean "more details"? For more details you can check Android source code. Why do you want to keep a client socket open forever?

Comment: The issue is in the server, all idle clients are disconnected automatically